# Optimizing the value N to split arrays up for vectorizing an array so it runs the quickest

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, octave, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to optimizing the value **N** to split arrays up for vectorizing an array so it runs the quickest on different machines. I have some test code below

```
#example use random values
clear all,
t=rand(1,556790);
inner_freq=rand(8193,6);

N=100; # use N chunks
nn = int32(linspace(1, length(t)+1, N+1))
aa_sig_combined=zeros(size(t));
total_time_so_far=0;
for ii=1:N
    tic;
    ind = nn(ii):nn(ii+1)-1;
    aa_sig_combined(ind) = sum(diag(inner_freq(1:end-1,2)) * cos(2 .* pi .* inner_freq(1:end-1,1) * t(ind)) .+ repmat(inner_freq(1:end-1,3),[1 length(ind)]));
    toc
    total_time_so_far=total_time_so_far+sum(toc)
end
fprintf('- Complete  test in %4.4fsec or %4.4fmins\n',total_time_so_far,total_time_so_far/60);
```

**This takes 162.7963sec or 2.7133mins to complete when N=100 on a 16gig i7 machine running ubuntu**

Is there a way to find out what value **N** should be to get this to run the fastest on different machines?

PS: I'm running Octave 3.8.1 on 16gig i7 ubuntu 14.04 but it will also be running on even a 1 gig raspberry pi 2.

Comment: If you are so concerned with performance, I'd write the loop in Fortran or C and then parallelize it (perhaps with OpenMP). 
You might also try precomputing some things outside of your main loop, such as length(ind) or inner_freq(1:end-1,1).

Comment: @krisdestruction I would love to but your code doesn't seem to work... I included the error's in the section under your answer.  I tried it multiple places online along with http://octave-online.net/ and errors with 'A' along with error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 8192x8192, op2 is 1x5568)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the Matlab test script that I used to time each parameter. The return is used to break it after the first iteration as it looks like the rest of the iterations are similar.

```
%example use random values
clear all;
t=rand(1,556790);
inner_freq=rand(8193,6);

N=100; % use N chunks
nn = int32( linspace(1, length(t)+1, N+1) );
aa_sig_combined=zeros(size(t));

D = diag(inner_freq(1:end-1,2));
for ii=1:N
    ind = nn(ii):nn(ii+1)-1;
    tic;
    cosPara = 2 * pi * A * t(ind);
    toc;
    cosResult = cos( cosPara );
    sumParaA = D * cosResult;
    toc;
    sumParaB = repmat(inner_freq(1:end-1,3),[1 length(ind)]);
    toc;
    aa_sig_combined(ind) = sum( sumParaA + sumParaB );
    toc;
    return;
end
```

The output is indicated as follows. Note that I have a slow computer.

```
Elapsed time is 0.156621 seconds.
Elapsed time is 17.384735 seconds.
Elapsed time is 17.922553 seconds.
Elapsed time is 18.452994 seconds.
```

As you can see, the cos operation is what's taking so long. You are running `cos` on a 8192x5568 matrix (45,613,056 elements) which makes sense that it takes so long.

If you wish to improve performance, use `parfor` as it appears each iteration is independent. Assuming you had 100 cores to run your 100 iterations, your script would be done in **17** seconds + `parfor` overhead.

Within the `cos` calculation, you might want to look into if another method exists to calculate cos of a value faster and more parallel than the stock method.

Another minor optimization is this line. It ensures that the `diag` function isn't called within the loop as the diagonal matrix is constant. You don't want a 8192x8192 diagonal matrix to be generated every time! I just stored it outside the loop and it gives a bit of a performance boost as well.

```
D = diag(inner_freq(1:end-1,2));
```

Note that I didn't use the Matlab profile as it didn't work for me, but you should use that in the future for more functionalized code.

Comment: I keep getting an error where 'A' is not defined and an error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 8192x8192, op2 is 1x5568)
error: called from:
error:   /home/rt/Documents/octave/eq_research/main/transform/test_loop_speed.m at line 18, column 14

Comment: Also I'm using Octave 3.8.1 which parfor isn't fully supported yet
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24970519/how-to-use-parallel-for-loop-in-octave-or-scilab