# Splitting up FOR loop for vectorizing so it runs quicker coding issue

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, octave, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize and split up a FOR loop to make it run faster but the variable "**aa_sig_combined_vect**" begins to return **nothing but zeros after cell 5569** any idea how to fix this? see code below that The user *krisdestruction* helped me with:

Please note I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Octave 3.8.1 which is like matlab but is missing some commands unfortunately the parfor command isn't fully implemented in this version of octave.

```
t=rand(1,556790);
inner_freq=rand(8193,6);

N=100; % use N chunks
nn = int32( linspace(1, length(t)+1, N+1) );
aa_sig_combined_vect=zeros(size(t));
total_time_so_far=0;

D = diag(inner_freq(1:end-1,2));
A = inner_freq(1:end-1,1);
for ii=1:N
    ind = nn(ii):nn(ii+1)-1;
    tic;
    cosPara = 2 * pi * A * t(ind);
    toc;
    cosResult = cos( cosPara );
    sumParaA = D * cosResult;
    toc;
    sumParaB = repmat(inner_freq(1:end-1,3),[1 length(ind)]);
    toc;
    aa_sig_combined_vect(ind) = sum( sumParaA + sumParaB );
    toc;
    total_time_so_far=total_time_so_far+sum(toc)
    return;
end
fprintf('- Complete  test in %4.4fsec or %4.4fmins\n',total_time_so_far,total_time_so_far/60);
```

The original working loop I'm trying to improve the speed of is below

```
clear all,
t=rand(1,556790);
inner_freq=rand(8193,6);

N=100; # use N chunks
nn = int32(linspace(1, length(t)+1, N+1))
aa_sig_combined=zeros(size(t));
total_time_so_far=0;

for ii=1:N
    tic;
    ind = nn(ii):nn(ii+1)-1;
    aa_sig_combined(ind) = sum(diag(inner_freq(1:end-1,2)) * cos(2 .* pi .* inner_freq(1:end-1,1) * t(ind)) .+ repmat(inner_freq(1:end-1,3),[1 length(ind)]));
    toc
    total_time_so_far=total_time_so_far+sum(toc)
end
fprintf('- Complete  test in %4.4fsec or %4.4fmins\n',total_time_so_far,total_time_so_far/60);

RMSERepmat = sqrt(mean((aa_sig_combined-aa_sig_combined_vect).^2)) %root men square error between two arrays lower is better
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason is fairly obvious. `return` has been added to the loop, breaking it after the first iteration. I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710229/2092048) where this code originates, and you might have noted this:

> The return is used to break it after the first iteration as it looks like the rest of the iterations are similar.

More generally:
Adding `tic/toc` in the loop is actually going to slow things down. Anything that prints to the screen slows your code down. There is [inbuilt profiling](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Profiling.html) in both MATLAB and Octave which should be used for trying to figure out what your bottlenecks are.

Also, this line doesn't change during the loop, because `inner_freq` doesn't and while `ind` does, `length(ind)` should be the same:

```
repmat(inner_freq(1:end-1,3),[1 length(ind)]);
```

So you can move that out as well, and avoid multiple calls to `repmat`.

Comment: thanks for the help I did what you said and when I move repmat(inner_freq(1:end-1,3),[1 length(ind)]);  out of the for loop it runs for about 7 iterations then I get an error.  "error: test_vector_speed.m: operator +: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 8192x5567, op2 is 8192x5568)
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error: called from:
error:   /home/rt/Documents/octave/eq_research/main/transform/test_vector_speed.m at line 46, column 28."  which points to a problem in the line aa_sig_combined_vect(ind) = sum( sumParaA + sumParaB );

Comment: that's because your number of samples isn't evenly dividable. You could add some error checking to catch that and then subindex e.g. use repmat once to make a  8192x5568 and then use something like `sumParaB(:,1:length(ind))`