# Speeding up findpeaks in octave using parallel computing

Tags: octave, parfor, octave-gui

I am modeling and interference measurement and want to find the number of fringes that cross a detector.  The data is fairly dense and it causes problems in findpeaks, and I was trying to use parfor to speed it up.  Of course parfor doesn't exist in octave, so I was wondering the best way to handle this issue.

This is what I tried initially;

````
```
parfor i = 1:N
  start = round(((i-1)/N)*length(IT))+1;
  stop = round((i/N)*length(IT));
  partime = time(start:stop);
  [row,col] = findpeaks(IT(start:stop)./max(IT(start:stop)));  % Fringe Frequency
  pklk = [pklk partime(col)];
end
```
````

Comment: Except when the peaks are flat, this should return the same result: `[~,col] = findpeaks(IT); pklk = time(col);`. No need to use loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25432257/7328782

Comment: @rahnema1; I am breaking up a vector into sections because it is excessively long and my machine runs out of memory finding peaks all at once.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, I think my instance of parfor will require multiple input variables to run, IT, start and stop.  This could be just two, i and IT, but how do I implement pararrayfun with multiple inputs to the function?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation of `findpeaks` using regex:

```
findpeaks = @(data) regexp(char(sign(diff(reshape(data, 1, []))) + '1'), '21*0') + 1;
```

That returns the positions of the peaks. Use it as:

```
col = findpeaks(IT); 
pklk = time(col);
```

The Octave implementation of `findpeaks` uses `bsxfun` to expand the index vector that require `n^2` memory.

**UPDATE**

Two more options `height` and `dist` are added. Moreover  the function now has two outputs: `pks` local maxima and `locs` peak locations.

```
function [pks, locs]  = findpeaks(data, height, dist)
  % find all peaks
  locs = regexp(char(sign(diff(reshape(data, 1, []))) + '1'), '21*0') + 1;
  % apply MinPeakHeight
  locs = locs(data(locs) > height) ;
  % apply MinPeakDistance 
  [~, isorted] = sort(data(locs), 'descend');
  n = numel(data);
  idx = false(1, n);
  idx(locs) = true;
  for s = reshape(locs(isorted), 1, [])
    if (idx(s))
      idx(max(s - dist, 1):min(s + dist, n)) = 0;
      idx(s) = 1;
    end
  end
  locs = find(idx);
  pks = data(locs);
end
```

Comment: I thought I’d seen it all, but you proved me wrong. `regexp` to find peaks… 

Comment: I will try this, thanks!!

Comment: I have some questions after trying.  First, this reduced the time per loop iteration by an order of magnitude, however; there is now a variance in the results.  I'm wondering if it is due to the limits I set in the findpeaks original code, that I am no longer setting; for instance peakheight and distance (these were not included in the orignal statement of the question because I thought they might be irrelevant).